# Why those two std::string find() functions are declared as noexcept?

Tags: c++, string, c++20, noexcept, string-view

According to [[string.find#1.2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.find#1.2) and [[string.find#1.3]](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.find#1.3):

> Each member function of the form
>
> - `constexpr size_type F(const charT* s, size_type pos) const;`
>
> has effects equivalent to: `return F(basic_­string_­view<charT, traits>(s), pos);`

> Each member function of the form
>
> - `constexpr size_type F(const charT* s, size_type pos, size_type n) const;`
>
> has effects equivalent to: `return F(basic_­string_­view<charT, traits>(s, n), pos);`

Those two `find` functions are not declared as `noexcept`, but [all](https://godbolt.org/z/WW41T6) of three compiler vendors didn't follow the rule, they just implement it as `noexcept`.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Why would it need to throw?

Comment: And adding noexcept wouldn't really violate the standard, as it's still source-code-compatible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the so-called Lakos rule. See [N3248](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3248.pdf). The rule is that if a function has a precondition, it should not be marked `noexcept` because it prevents an implementation from checking the precondition and throwing an exception on validation, if the implementation would choose to do that.

In this case, `find(s, pos, n)` is equivalent to `find(string_view(s, n), pos)`. And that `string_view(s, n)` construction has a precondition that `s` is a valid string of length at least `n`. So an implementation *could* try to validate that somehow and throw an exception on failure.

But none of the implementations actually try to validate this, so they don't take the freedom of potentially throwing on precondition violation, and instead simply mark these functions as `noexcept`. Which they're allowed to do from [[res.on.exception.handling]](http://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.exception.handling):

> An implementation may strengthen the exception specification for a non-virtual function by adding a non-throwing exception specification.

---

Library Evolution has recently accepted [P1656](https://wg21.link/p1656) which basically reverts the Lakos Rule.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find the answer.

According to the [[res.on.exception.handling]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/res.on.exception.handling#5):

> An implementation may strengthen the exception specification for a non-virtual function by adding a non-throwing exception specification.

So they are free to mark this overload `noexcept`. Thank you for your attention.