# why is std::midpoint not noexcept for pointers?

Tags: c++, c++20, noexcept

c++20 introduces [std::midpoint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/midpoint):

```cpp
template< class T >
constexpr T midpoint( T a, T b ) noexcept;

template< class T >
constexpr T* midpoint( T* a, T* b );
```

Both gcc and clang [make it `noexcept`](https://godbolt.org/z/7z5hxjqj9) though.

Comment: This is the so-called [Lakos rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66603543/why-those-two-stdstring-find-functions-are-declared-as-noexcept).

Comment: thank you, i see. Lakos rule is basically saying that `noexcept` on functions with precondictions will prevent the implementation from validating preconditions. But IMO it doesn't, because a implementation can validate preconditions and even throw exceptions in noexcept functions, which terminates the program. On the other hand, if an implementation want to throw an implementation-defined exception that can be `catch`-ed by caller, users have to write non-portable source code.